# Warning: The definition depended on by in the SWC could not be found

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop, swc

Help.
I compiled with flashdevelop a "swc" of the SVGRenderer for as3 (https://github.com/LucasLorentz/AS3SVGRenderer)
When I compile the SWC project, I don't have any issues. But when I import them in my AS3 AIR project, FlashDevelops outputs the following alerts (not errors):

```
C:\Users\Usuario\IlliaTV_editor\lib\SVGRenderer.swc
Warning: The definition com.lorentz.SVG.svg_internal depended on by com.lorentz.SVG.display.base.SVGElement in the SWC C:\Users\Usuario\IlliaTV_editor\lib\SVGRenderer.swc could not be found

C:\Users\Usuario\IlliaTV_editor\lib\SVGRenderer.swc
Warning: The definition com.lorentz.SVG.svg_internal depended on by com.lorentz.SVG.display.SVGTSpan in the SWC C:\Users\Usuario\IlliaTV_editor\lib\SVGRenderer.swc could not be found

C:\Users\Usuario\IlliaTV_editor\lib\SVGRenderer.swc
Warning: The definition com.lorentz.SVG.svg_internal depended on by com.lorentz.SVG.display.SVGDocument in the SWC C:\Users\Usuario\IlliaTV_editor\lib\SVGRenderer.swc could not be found

C:\Users\Usuario\IlliaTV_editor\lib\SVGRenderer.swc
Warning: The definition com.lorentz.SVG.svg_internal depended on by      com.lorentz.SVG.display.base.SVGTextContainer in the SWC       C:\Users\Usuario\IlliaTV_editor\lib\SVGRenderer.swc could not be found
```

I have no idea why the alerts appears. The code works fine, it loads the svg image file and show it correctly, but I don't want those alerts showing in the output console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing project --> properties --> Build Path --> Link type to "merged" fixed this for me.

You then get compiler warnings, which I haven't figured out how to fix.